# Power up Bluetooth speaker with voice command (Megaboom 3)

Tags: applications, automation, google-assistant, voice-command

I am trying to make a Google Assistant Routine:

1. Power on Bluetooth.
2. Wait for two seconds.
3. Use the app [BOOM Switch](https://github.com/Shingyx/BoomSwitch) to power up two paired Megaboom 3.
4. Set media volume to 30%.
5. Start a Spotify playlist.

The 3rd step is my problem.

The app "Boom Switch" is not in Google Home Assistant shortcuts. The app itself can create widgets/shortcuts to the home screen which can activate 1 speaker at a time with a click/tab.

---

- Starters

  - Voice command: "Hey Google, let's party"
- Actions

  - "Activate Bluetooth"
  - Delay: 2 seconds
  - [Open Boom Switch speaker_one] <- [need correct phrasing set up]
  - Delay: 2 seconds
  - [Open Boom Switch speaker_two] <- [need correct phrasing set up]
  - "Set media volume to 30%"
  - "Open Spotify playlist"

I hope you can solve this.

Comment: Have you tried using task apps such as `IFTTT` or `Automate`